# How to make a probabilistic inference about a regression of count data?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, inference, count-data

I am trying to build a linear model that can be used to make an inference. Both the dependent and independent variables are count data. Specifically, I want to know given a value of the independent variable, what is the probability of finding greater than some value n for the dependent variable.

```
Dependent <- c(1,6,18,6,5,1,2,22,2,2,1,5,11,7,3,5,1,7,1,1,16,2,2,2,2,7,6,1)
Independent <- c(1,3,4,4,3,3,1,10,1,1,1,4,4,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,6,1,2,2,2,5,2,2)
```

Because the data are counts I ran a poisson regression.

```
glm(Dependent~Independent,family = poisson)
```

But I don't know how to take this and turn it into an inference. If I were running an OLS regression, I'd be inclined to take the stdev of the residuals to and use them create a probability distribution around the predicted results. Something like this:

```
infer <- function(x,model,y){
  m <- model$coefficients[2] * x + model$coefficients[1]
  s <- resid(model)
  pr <- pnorm(y+1,mean=m,sd = fitdist(s,"norm")$estimate[2],lower.tail = FALSE)
  return(pr)
}
```

pr should be the probability of observing a value for the dependent variable that is greater than y+1 given a certain value x. I used y+1 because the data are counts, so knowing the probability of a result >y isn't that helpful. Is this whole approach even valid?  And if it is, how would I transfer that to a poisson distribution? R's glm() function uses the log of the data. So the residuals are also logged, which is confusing me to no end. I tried this, and the outputs kind of make sense but I'm not confident it's giving me the output I want. I also notice that I'm no longer using the residuals, which I think is fine because the poisson distribution is based on lambda rather than deviations?:

```
infer <- function(x,model,y){
  m <- model$coefficients[2] * x + model$coefficients[1]
  p <- ppois(log(y+1),m,lower.tail = FALSE)
  return(p)
```

So in short, does this work? And if this is approach not valid, how would I go about solving my problem?